# How to center nav-item and right align another one in Bootstrap 4 navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass

I have the following code:

```html
<div class="container-fluid big-logo bg-light" id="big-logo">
    <nav class="navbar nav-pills flex-column justify-content-center flex-sm-row navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="nav-item">
            <img alt="logo" src="{% static 'img/fuck.jpg' %}" style="max-height:40px;">
        </a>
        <a href="{% url 'cart' %}" class="nav-item">
            <div>
                <img alt="cart" class="card-title" src="{% static 'img/cart.png' %}" style="max-height:30px;">
                <span class='badge badge-warning' id='lblCartCount'> {{ obj }} </span>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Cart</h6>
            </div>
        </a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

This is how the current and the expected results:

[image]

I have tried many options but nothing can be done. How can I do to get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use and `m-auto` and `ml-auto` class on the anchor tag to align it to right. Remove `justify-content-center` from `nav`:

```
<div class="container-fluid big-logo bg-light" id="big-logo">
            <nav class="navbar nav-pills flex-column flex-sm-row navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">
                <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="nav-item m-auto">
                    <img alt="logo" src="{% static 'img/fuck.jpg' %}" style="max-height:40px;">
                </a>
                <a href="{% url 'cart' %}" class="nav-item ml-auto">
                    <div>
                        <img alt="cart" class="card-title" src="{% static 'img/cart.png' %}" style="max-height:30px;">
                        <span class='badge badge-warning' id='lblCartCount'> {{ obj }} </span>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Cart</h6>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use `mx-md-auto`, example navbar: (run code on full page)**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark main-nav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse nav-content order-2">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-nowrap flex-row mx-md-auto order-1 order-md-2">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Center</a></li>
            <button class="navbar-toggler ml-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </ul>
        <div class="ml-auto navbar-collapse collapse nav-content order-3 order-md-3">
            <ul class="ml-auto nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```